# Can fstream read online .txt file?

Tags: visual-c++

How can I make my `fstream` read online .txt file in my file server? I always get an error opening the file, can it not be read online?

Here's my sample code for this:

```cpp
if stream infile;
infile.open("https://script-autopot.000webhostapp.com/license.txt");
if (infile.fail()) {
    cout << "Error Opening File";
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please post the error you are getting, also check that you can access that file publicly.

TBH I would be using a web api that this hits with authentication, then it can send back a json or text stream.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's not possible in the way you think. In C++, fstream is a file stream. It's used for working with files. What you probably were thinking of is a "stream" for "data from the network", and that could be achieved with the base i/o stream classes, but not with the fstream. However, if you wrote it, or found a library that does it this way, the 'stream' would only be the final last object you'd interact with, and there'd be more factory classes before that, because setting up network/passwords/headers/certificates/younameit for all the HTTP/S/1/2/3 can get pretty complex. Much more complex than simple "here's the URL".

So.. maybe take a look at good old https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html?
Or newer things like https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib?
I suppose you could find a few like this by googling "C++ https client".

Finally, if you're really bound to use fstream, then yes, there's a "everything is a file" saying in linux/unix terminology. You could technically open a `wget`-like process, bind its inputs/outputs to a file-based named-pipe, then open that file with a fstream and read/write from it like from a file.